# Array of objects to Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an array of like

```
 var data: [UserModal] = [
        UserModal(unit: "Unit 1", data: [
            ScoreModal(name: "Ney", score: 10 ),
            ScoreModal(name: "Mes", score: 20 ),
            ScoreModal(name: "Ro", score: 30 ),
            ScoreModal(name: "Su", score: 40 ),
        ]),
        UserModal(unit: "Unit 2", data: [
            ScoreModal(name: "Ney", score: 10 ),
            ScoreModal(name: "Mes", score: 20 ),
            ScoreModal(name: "Ro", score: 30 ),
            ScoreModal(name: "Su", score: 40 ),
        ]),
        UserModal(unit: "Unit 3", data: [
            ScoreModal(name: "Ney", score: 10 ),
            ScoreModal(name: "Mes", score: 20 ),
            ScoreModal(name: "Ro", score: 30 ),
            ScoreModal(name: "Su", score: 40 ),
        ]),
    ]
```

I want to calculate the total score of the members like:

```
  var result: [ScoreModal] = [
        ScoreModal(name: "Ney", score: 30 ),
        ScoreModal(name: "Mes", score: 60 ),
        ScoreModal(name: "Ro", score: 90 ),
        ScoreModal(name: "Su", score: 120 ),
    ]
```

I tried to manipulate the map but it didn't work
please help me

Comment: There's no dictionary in your data or result. Please show what you have tried so far. Explain what problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple `forEach` loops and a `filter`, will calculate the total score of the members, like the `results` you show:

```
var result: [ScoreModal] = []

["Ney","Mes","Ro","Su"].forEach{ key in
    var totalScore = 0
    data.forEach{ user in
        user.data.filter{ $0.name == key}.forEach{ totalScore += $0.score }
    }
    result.append(ScoreModal(name: key, score: totalScore))
}

print("---> result: \(result)")
```

Note, if you don't want to use the array of keys, replace it with:

```
 Set(data.map{$0.data.map{$0.name}}.flatMap{$0}).forEach{ key in
   ....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Accept [@Sumida's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76479363/22000500) answer i just made update for dynamic keys.

```
var nameArray = data.map { model in
    var array = [String]()
    guard let arrayModel = model.data else {
        return array
    }
    for data in arrayModel {
        array.append(data.name ?? "")
    }
    return array
}
let flattenedArray = nameArray.reduce([], +)
print(flattenedArray)

let uniqueArray = Array(Set(flattenedArray))
print(uniqueArray)

var scoreModal: [ScoreModal] = []

uniqueArray.forEach{ key in
    var totalScore = 0
    data.forEach{ user in
        user.data?.filter{ $0.name == key}.forEach{ totalScore += $0.score ?? 0 }
    }
    scoreModal.append(ScoreModal(name: key, score: totalScore))
}

print("ScoreModal: \(scoreModal)")
```